# How do you filter/select a <select>'s <option> by the contents of the option tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, filter

I have found plenty of answers about how to extract the value of an `<option>` tag, or the contents of the tag itself, `content here'

However, I am wondering if there is a way to select an option by the text value of the `<option>text here</option>` - in this case, using `text here` as a matching term.

I am building a pretty simple form for internal use - that will effectively limit the number of options in a second dropdown based on the selection of the first dropdown. However, since this is part of a CMS, using the `value` attribute of the block is not going to be a reliable effort. I know that the spelling and the wording of the text parameter of the dropdown is important, and will be what I need it to be.

I know this is not a good practice - believe me I know that. However, right now this is something I need to get done quickly and with as little time invested in this as possible. Without reinventing or redoing all the logic for this decade-old tool, I would opt for this route.

So, is it possible to filter by the inner text of the tag? I KNOW you can extract it, but we want to filter so we can limit the options the user can select from.

```
    <select id="one">
        <option value="a">eh</option>
        <option value="b">bee</option>
    </select>

    <select id="two">
        <option value="m">emm</option>
        <option value="lw">lolwot</option>
        <option value="p">dinner</option>
    </select>
```

In this case, if they select 'b' from first drop down -- it will limit their selection to -only- `lolwot` on the second dropdown - removing `emm` and `dinner`.

Just to reiterate, I do not want to extract from a selected option. `$('#two').find('option:selected').text()` is not what I am looking for.

Comment: can you explain how "b" in the first drop down is related to "lw" in the second?

Comment: Also, are you looking for `$('#two option:contains("lolwot")')` ?

Comment: Need to know the logic or lack of logic involved in determining what specifically happens when select A has a selected text and how select B knows what to remove? Like @devlincarnate already commented > why is "bee" = "lowot"?

Comment: They are just example values

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Assuming that you want to keep the one having the inner text of lolwot, you can do the following:

```
[...document.getElementById("two").children].forEach((item) => {if (item.innerText !== "lolwot") item.remove()})
```

- we get the item by id and its children inside the square brackets
- we convert that to an array, so we have an array of children
- we iterate this array
- if the current item does not meet the criteria, we simply remove it

If you want to get the items to remove, then you can filter:

```
[...document.getElementById("two").children].filter((item) => (item.innerText !== "lolwot"))
```